# MySQL create a table from two existing table calculations

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, yii

I'm making a php web page with Yii and MySQL. My problem is in database part.

I have two tables, "stock" and "given". They are like:

```
stock = id (primary key), name, amount (this is integer), details
```

and

```
given = id (from stock), name (from stock), amount (given amount, thus not same with stock), ...
```

I want to create a table "leftStock" which is the same format with "stock" but has different amount. It will be the number left in stock after given some. Since in different times, different amounts of the same item may be given, the given table's id and name is not unique. Thus i'll use "sum(given.amount)" but its not definite for me.

I thought i can use "create table...select" style coding but i could not construct its structure. Can anybody help me?

(Also can i use "view" in a Yii web page? Because i won't make any direct change on "leftStock" table, its being view may be feasible either.)

Comment: left is a keyword so you want be able to use it as a table name (or field name)

Comment: try to create "VIEW" not "TABLE".

Comment: i used it to be understandable, not real name. still i can change it here not to be confused, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be done by creating a query too.

Try this, I dont test it yet:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(a.amount - b.amount) 
    FROM stock AS a, given AS b 
    WHERE a.id = b.id AND a.id = id) AS `itemleft`, *
FROM stock
```

Comment: i coded it: `create view leftStock as select (select sum(a.amount - b.amount from stock a, given b where a.id =b.id and a.id = id) as 'itemleft', * from stock` but it gave a syntax error and again i could not find where. as you know, mysql generally gives always syntax error.

Comment: @corrupt : Thanks for revision. I didnt notice that I use a single quote there.. Hehehe

Comment: @user1983481 : try the revised code. there was a single quote there, so it can gives you an error. If you already test the updated answer, I will say sorry that I cant help.